# Compose button title does not have enough space to display

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm going to make a numeric keyboard in one line by compose, but the title just does't display. Like so:

[image]

here is my code:

```
@Composable
    fun TopNumericalKey(values: List<Int>) {
        Row(Modifier.background(Color.Red)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(2.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)) {
            values.forEach {
                ElevatedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(containerColor = Color.Green, contentColor = Color.Red),
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                ) {
                    Text(text = it.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Preview(showBackground = true,)
    @Composable
    fun PreviewTopNumericalKey() {
        val list = (1.. 9).toMutableList()
        list.add(0)
        TopNumericalKey(values = list)
    }
```

If I remove `modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)`, then there's no enough width for all the buttons, it displays like this:

[image]

So I guess there's a default spacing for `ElevatedButton`, any way to make the title displays? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of default `contentPadding` values of `ElevatedButton`. You can set it to a value less than default 24.dp and you will be able to see `Text` inside it.

```
@Composable
fun ElevatedButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.elevatedShape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
)
```

Button defaults

```
private val ButtonHorizontalPadding = 24.dp
private val ButtonVerticalPadding = 8.dp
```